# MS Access 2007 - Update a Field in a Table with data from another Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

Ok - I have spent 2 hours trying to figure this out. Searching StackOverflow, Google, MSDN etc. I am lost.

I have found apparent valid answers for MSSQL and other SQL platforms in here, but they do NOT work for MS Access 2007 SQL.

Table 1 has fields ID and Name, Table 2 has the same fields.

In Table 1 I need to update the Name field with the same field from Table 2, Joined on the ID fields.

I have tried numerous Update queries to no avail.

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.Name = table2.Name 
WHERE table1.ID=table2.ID
```

No worky!

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.Name = (
SELECT Name From table2 Where Table2.ID=Table1.ID
)
```

The dreaded "must use an updateable query" message which I can't figure out a solution to.

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.Name=table2.Name
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
```

"Syntax error"!

My brain is fried. I swear I have done this numerous times in the past, but can't figure it out. I am sure this is simple and someone has a quick answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access has slightly different syntax for `update` with `join`.  You can try:

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN
       table2
       ON table1.ID = table2.ID
    SET table1.Name = table2.Name;
```

Comment: And OP, the `UPDATE...JOIN` here is shared by MySQL's dialect. Had you searched this *other SQL platform*, it could work for MS Access.